# Adding Guid to a list<Guid> leads to an Error C#

Tags: c#, guid

I am trying to create a list of Guids but this error occurs:

```
 {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}
```

My code is like this:

```
 public List<Group> GroupList=new List<Group>();
 string GroupsGuid = "9A4FA56F-EAA0-49AF-B7F0-8CA09EA39167";
 ItemsIndex.Add(GroupsGuid);
```

Sorry for the simple question.Despite a lot of research,I have come up empty.
Thanks.

Comment: `List<Guid> ItemsIndex = new List<Guid>();`

Comment: Thank you all,
I am really sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Accept one right answer

Comment: @hs.chandra:I have to wait for 7 minutes because the website says so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to create an instance of your list, right now it's `null`, this will do it:

```
List<Guid> ItemsIndex = new List<Guid>();
```

Answer (score 3):

One line missing:

```
ItemsIndex = new List<Guid>();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code there is object `ItemsIndex` which is NULL. and you are be trying to read property value of that object.

This is the reason for the Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Make this correction.

```
public Guid GroupsGuid;
List<Guid> ItemsIndex = new List<guid>();
GroupsGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
ItemsIndex.Add(GroupsGuid);
```

Comment: Stolen from here http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/414494/Object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code for example:

```cs
public Guid GroupsGuid;
GroupsGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
List<Guid> ItemsIndex = new List<Guid>(){ GroupsGuid };
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**